# SQL Select multiple distinct column rows as one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm not sure of a better way to word this, but say I have a table

```
name,    homephone,   fax,    mobile
========================================
bob,     123,         456,    999
chris,   null,        890,    null
```

I'm trying to create a SQL statement that will get me something like this

```
name,     phone
================
bob,      123
bob,      456
bob,      999
chris,    890
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using UNION? Say your table is called Directory. Something like:

```
SELECT name, homephone AS phone FROM Directory WHERE homephone IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT name, fax AS phone FROM Directory WHERE fax IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT name, mobile AS phone FROM Directory WHERE mobile IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select T.name, P.phone
from YourTale as T
  cross apply (
                select homephone union all
                select fax union all
                select mobile
              ) as P(phone)
where p.phone is not null
```

Comment: +1 I prefer this over Robert's solution, but Robert's is excellent as well.